# How can i verify mastercard and visa card in my shopping cart project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, credit-card

- My team working in a shopping cart project
- We have integrated First data payment Gateway
- Now we want to verify the master card and visa
- I need to authenticate the master card SecureCode based on the link given below
- http://www.mastercard.com/us/personal/en/cardholderservices/securecode/how_it_works.html
- Please provide any api or necessary information for doing the same

Comment: Here ya go... http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/fd_globalgatewayapi_usermanual.pdf

Answer (score 4):

To validate a credit card is legitimate:

1. Verify it against the [Luhn Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). (Will only validate the card number is in a valid format)
2. Verify the card number against known [Issuer Identification Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number)
3. Perform an Authorization Only (aka AUTH ONLY) for $0.00 (or $0.01 if your processor does not support zero auths). This is the only guaranteed way to verify a credit card exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, imho you need a payment provider to use credit card payment anyway - they'll give you a kind of api to check the data against.

Answer (score 0):

To at least validate the code is valid you can give this a try:
http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/web-mysql/web-scripts/luhn-algorithm-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mobilefish.com/services/credit_card_number_generator/credit_card_number_generator.php 
Check previous link it contains good description for luhn alog and have credit card generator